# How to query Google Drive spreadsheet from GWT

Tags: gwt, gdata, google-sheets-api

I have a GWT application that would like to read a Google Drive spreadsheet given a public read only url such as https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj9YCks8-__hdGU5RHFSRzk4WFNHT3RjRWlsVGdGT2c&usp=sharing.

I can read this from a browser in csv format using this url: https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0Aj9YCks8-__hdGU5RHFSRzk4WFNHT3RjRWlsVGdGT2c&exportFormat=csv&gid=0

However, this does not work unless the user is logged in as a google user.

Given a public spreadsheet key as shown above, how would one query the spreadsheet using server side queries or apis from GWT?  I've seen references to a GWT Drive API but nothing other than coming soon for the last year or so.

Comment: 2 ways that work: A) Google-apps-script (simple with good docs) B) Login with Google-drive (see DrEdit example). Thoughts:if it is your google account then google-apps-script is probably a good choice, if not than Google drive+Oauth might be better.

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser security, you can access to url in other domain than your server.
You must pass by your server to call your URL with a script proxy.